# return int with angular provider

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I return int type value form MVC method to angular.js function.
I can return object but i need to return single int type variable.

```
//Api controller 
[HttpGet]
        public int GetSelectedStockUsers(long StockId)
        {
            return 10;
        }

// Js code
 $scope.getSelectedStockUsers = function () {
            debugger;
            Stock.getStockUsers({ stockId: $scope.selectedStock.id }, function (res) {
                debugger;
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd return value in `Json` format rather

```
return Json(new { Value = 1 });
```

Comment: getStockUsers: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    cache: false,
                    isArray: true,
                    url: '/Api/Stock/GetSelectedStockUsers/:stockId'
                }

Comment: Is there need to change in provider??

Comment: Thanks Pankaj parker

Comment: And Is there any other way to return single type of variable e.g. int,string etc. in angular with MVC

Comment: If there is any way do it, I would not follow that..rather i would create one class & will return a value from it.. Is there any problem with suggested thing?

Comment: You are using $resource? You are getting any console errors?

Comment: Yes am using $resourse. There was also a error in console, But now i have completed with  return Json(new { Value = 1 }); Its working fine now thanks pankaj sir